# Xvfb not working on Red Hat Linux

Tags: headless, x11

I'm trying to get an X server going on a headless box and I'm using Xvfb.

Invocation:

```
 Xvfb -fbdir . &
```

Result

```
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root
Could not init font path element unix/:7100, removing from list!
```

Message when quitting:

```
FreeFontPath: FPE "built-ins" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.
```

Core Problem:

Attempting to run the headless Java test(I have another program that I'm actually trying to run, but this sample code reproduces the error) at http://www.j2ee.me/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/ gets me this error:

```
(.:31027): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this sounds dumb, but did you try `chown root:root /tmp/.X11-unix` to address that first warning when starting up?

Also, I think you're not using the appropriate DISPLAY variable when launching your program. Try `Xvfb -display :1`, then `DISPLAY=:1 ./yourprogram` and see if that works.

If display :1 is taken, try :2, etc.

Alternatively, you could consider VNC as it serves roughly the same purpose.

Comment: The DISPLAY variable *appears* to fix it. chown to root is strictly denied to me.